# What's the purpose of SQL language?

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql, innodb

After discovered [HandlerSocket](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html) and messed with many ORM, one thing that troubles me is:

Why SQL exists? At all?

Why can't database drivers provide a direct way to e.g. InnoDB, and wrap various operations inside the ORM library itself?

Why ORM -> SQL -> DB parse SQL -> Db engine operations?

Why can't ORM -> Db engine operations ?

Comment: Start by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: Stop downvoting. Let him learn. This is not terrible question, many newbies may be interested.

Comment: This question is an invitation to an open-ended discussion, rather than a "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". It's a sort of question [not appropriate for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). -1.

Comment: SQL is the vocabulary used to pass your potentially complex intentions to a relational database engine, these intentions have to be passed from a client layer *somehow*, an un-coupled *portable *standardised & human readable format is a pretty good choice for doing exactly that.

Comment: you would have done some googling before asking this question in stackoverflow..!

Comment: That is pretty good question, and it reveals how SQL is archaic.  Object oriented databases will be the future. Maybe its time to start working with them :)

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt It's almost an open question. Not exactly though as scientific evidence of the need for SQL CAN and have been provided. Those are pretty specific. After all I don't think he asked for anyone's opinion. Just a scientific explanation of the functional value of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, SQL was first, before any kind of ORM existed. A brief history

- First you stored your data in sequential files
- Later you used direct files (clients.dat)
- Later first non relational DBs appeared (Check [this](http://www.personal.psu.edu/glh10/ist110/topic/topic07/topic07_06.html))

And then someone has an idea of relational databases with a query language. Luckily we have an standard called SQL (even there are some small differences between different dialects of SQL in sql server, oracle, etc.)

And long time after (SQL is pretty old) someone invented ORM that uses sql to communicate with dbs.

There are also some efforts to have ORM->DB like no-sql dbs, object oriented dbs (OODBMS) and document

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of SQL `Structured Query Language` is to provide a `Structured` way by which one can `Query` information in database using a standard `Language`.

SQL provides a `global` standard of working with databases with little or not differences over different platform. For e.g. if you are familiar with SQL you can work with major DBs like `SQL Server` `mySql` & `Oracle` *few minor differences in syntax exists but they aren’t very prominent at least as far as basic operations are concerned*.

Answer (score 0):

When using an ORM you just replace SQL with something else e.g. Hibernate's HQL.

And SQL does a lot of work in background for you, that you would need to implement manually. SQL was designed such that you state what the result of your query should be. You then let the database figure out how to do it.

Think about something like:

> *Get me all employees who were hired in 2011 and have a salary that is 20% higher than the average salary of the department they work in.*

Doing this in SQL is not that complicated.

```
select name, 
       salary,
       deptno,
       hire_date
from (
   select name, 
          salary, 
          deptno,
          avg(salary) over (partition by deptno) as avg_detp_salary,
          hire_date
   from employee
   where extract(year from hire_date) = 2011    
) as t
where salary >= avg_dept_salary * 1.20;
```

Now think about how you'd do this if you did not have a query language (neither SQL nor an ORM query language)

Answer (score -1):

It exists because many people using it. There are many very good tools compatibile with SQL. ODBC, JDBC.

I think SQL is very archaic, but there is nothing better, that will work with almost any database engine and allows you to manipulate data with functionality of SQL.

There are some modern tools to work with data, more comfortable to use with today needs - ORM, Linq, OLAP but they have diffrent purposes, they are not compatibile.

And one more thing - you messed with many ORM's. That is the problem. There are many ORM's, incompatibile, people have to learn each other. SQL is one language (some small diferences in diffrent database engines.

Comment: Actually the differences in SQL dialects are nearly as big as those in the ORM query languages.